# Proving that a complex function is real valued on an interval

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $V = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| > 1\}$ and $f \in H(V)$. Assume that $f$ is real-valued on $(1,\infty)$. Show that it is real valued on $(-\infty, -1)$.

This is a problem from a complex analysis course. I'm not sure what technique I should use here to prove this. At first, I thought the Cauchy-Riemann equations might be useful here but I don't think that is the right path anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $V$ is conjugate invariant the function $g(z)=\overline {f(\bar z)}$ is defined and holomorphic on $V$. By hypothesis $g=f$ on $(1,\infty)$ hence everywhere on $V$, so in particular $f$ is real on all reals in $V$ hence on $(-\infty,-1)$ too